# how to print a sum of column in all rows in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

lets say I have a table named "myPlayerInfo" with following rows

```
'player name' 'number of goals'
'john'        '10'
'martin'      '20'
'jen'         '20'
```

Q1. How do I write an sql query that prints a new column which is sum of 'number of goals' column ?

```
'player name' 'number of goals'  'Total goals by all players'
'john'        '10'               '50'
'martin'      '20'               '50'
'jen'         '20'               '50'
```

Q2. How do I write an sql query that prints a new column which is % of goals scored by each player  with the total goals column we did in Q1. ?

```
'player name' 'number of goals' '% goals scored'  'Total goals by all players'
'john'        '10'              '20'                  '50'
'martin'      '20'              '40'                  '50'
'jen'         '20'              '40'                  '50'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a cartesian join of the total sum of all rows, derived from a subselect:

```
SELECT 
    a.player_name, 
    a.number_of_goals, 
    (a.number_of_goals / b.goalsum)*100 AS percent_scored,
    b.goalsum
FROM   
    myPlayerInfo a
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT SUM(number_of_goals) AS goalsum FROM myPlayerInfo) b
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a window function:

```
select
    player_name,
    number_of_goals,
    (number_of_goals * 100) / SUM(number_of_goals) OVER () AS percent_goals_scored,
    SUM([number of goals]) OVER () AS total_goals_by_all_players
from myPlayerInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like `SELECT name, goals, sum(goals) as sum, goals/sum(goals) as relgoals FROM table;`?

Comment: `'goals'/sum('goals')` is invalid. `'goals'` is a character literal. Not a number nor a column reference. You probably mean `goals` (without any quotes).

Comment: Yes, you are right, haven't figured out, how to use backticks in code blocks. Removed the single quotes now.

Comment: You don't need the backticks for those column names and "outside" of MySQL they are illegal anyway. But if you really want to use them just highlight the code (including the backticks) and click on the `{}` button.